# Jenkins Execute shell if then statement fails with `Bad substitution`

Tags: bash, jenkins

I need an if statement in Jenkins Execute Shell, but it always fails on the same line, regardless of what’s there.
I’m trying to do something like this:

```
if [ " ${BuildVariants[*]} " =~ " VariantA " ]; then
    # fails on this line even this line is just a comment
    variant_config=""
fi
```

it fails when I try to assign a variable there, fails when I try to `echo "anything"`, fails even on comment (as example above)

Reason: `Bad substitution`

*Note: There's anything specified in Configure System, so it should be using default Bash.*

What the problem might be?

Comment: Aside from the correct answer given by Joe Casadonte, I would run the code with `set -x` enabled to see what's going on, and do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` in your script to verify that you are really using bash. Further, are you sure that you really want to search for the substring _VariantA_, **surrounded by spaces**?, Also, did you ensure that `BuildVariants` is an array? I don't see how you initialize this variable. Finally, I don't think that you postet the **complete** error message.

Comment: Then you run shell scripts in jenkins pipeline, it still using groovy syntax. Suppose you need to use "\" to screen special symbols.

Comment: @user1934428 yup that's exactly what the problem was -  I supposed Jenkins was giving me an array, but it was giving a string. Thank you!
It is initialized with Extended Choice Parameter, with multiple choices.

Comment: I don't think that Jenkins technically **can** pass you an array. Your script is  run as a child process and there is no general mechanism to pass arrays as parameters to processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I supposed Jenkins was giving me an array, but it was giving me a string. (I used with ***Extended Choice Parameter***, with multiple choices).

So the condition should've been `[[ "$BuildVariants" == *"VariantA"* ]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `=~` works inside of `[ ... ]` -- use `[[ ... ]]` instead.

[Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) is a great tool for find these types of things; it would show that you've hit [SC2074](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2074).

re:

> ## fails on this line even this line is just a comment

You cannot have an "empty" `then` block. You can use just `:` as code to be executed:

```
if [[ "$foo" == "bar" ]]; then
:
fi
```

Next idea: get your code to run in a shell script, then put the code up in Jenkins. You will probably need to mock up some of the Jenkins-supplied input to do that, but it takes one more moving part out of the equation. If the code runs from the command line and doesn't in Jenkins, then you need to start looking for Jenkins-specific causes, like maybe it's being run in a csh instead of Bash (I see you mention this specific possibility already, but maybe there's something else like it -- I don't know Jenkins, sorry).

Comment: I tried `[[ ... ]]` too, the same. Should've mentioned this

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem was exactly in me trying to run the command in an online bash tool and mocking some inputs :sweat_smile: my script worked there, but not in Jenkins.
I supposed Jenkins was giving me an array, but it was giving a string.

So now I'm getting `[[: not found` error but at least that `Bad substitution` one is fixed haha

Thanks again for help!

Comment: The `[[: not found` error suggests it's running in a shell other than bash (probably dash).

Comment: @GordonDavisson `[[: not found` this one was fixed after I added `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the command window (not sure if it confirms your suggestion). Thanks in any case!